# How can I show this array on screen?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date

guys, I got a problem for you :)

There are 31 students in my class, I need to show the names of 2 students (in the order from the array of names) on-screen Monday to Friday, and show WEEKEND on-screen on Saturday and Sunday, and when the array of names is finished I need it to start all over again (a loop); 
 The code below is my take on the problem but I keep getting undefined and I don't know why or if my method is even good for resolving the problem.

```js
let dayNr = new Date().getDay();
let names1 = ['name1', 'name3', 'name5', 'name7', 'name9', 'name11', 'name13', 'name15', 'name17', 'name19', 'name21', 'name23', 'name25', 'name27', 'name29', 'name31'];
let names2 = ['name2', 'name4', 'name6', 'name8', 'name10', 'name12', 'name14', 'name16', 'name18', 'name20', 'name22', 'name24', 'name26', 'name28', 'name30'];
let n1 = names1.length;
let n2 = names2.length;


if (dayNr === 0 || dayNr === 6) {
  document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = "WEEKEND";
  document.getElementById("secondName").innerHTML = "WEEKEND";
} else {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  while (i <= n1) {
    document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = names1[i];
    i++;
  }
  i = 0;

  while (j <= n2) {
    document.getElementById("secondName").innerHTML = names2[j];
    j++;
  }
  j = 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 colTop py-3 mb-4">
  <h1 class="text-white">STUDENTS IN CLASS</h1>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td id="firstName"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="secondName"></td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you just want to show 2 names each Monday to Friday, you need to have a start date to show names 1 and 2 so that for each day after that the next pair of names can be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the following reasons you have faced the issue:

1. You have been overwriting the td inner html due to which only one
   name is being printed.
2. In the while loop condition you have checked less than equals to the
   length of the array and since there won't be any value in the final
   loop it's showing undefined.

Hence, fixing those two issues your problem will be solved as I have shown in the following code:

```js
let dayNr = new Date().getDay();
let names1 = ['name1', 'name3', 'name5', 'name7', 'name9', 'name11', 'name13', 'name15', 'name17', 'name19', 'name21', 'name23', 'name25', 'name27', 'name29', 'name31'];
let names2 = ['name2', 'name4', 'name6', 'name8', 'name10', 'name12', 'name14', 'name16', 'name18', 'name20', 'name22', 'name24', 'name26', 'name28', 'name30'];
let n1 = names1.length;
let n2 = names2.length;

if (dayNr === 0 || dayNr === 6) {
  document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = "WEEKEND";
  document.getElementById("secondName").innerHTML = "WEEKEND";
} else {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  while (i < n1) {
    let firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    const delimiter = firstName.innerHTML !== '' ? ',' : '';
    firstName.innerHTML =`${firstName.innerHTML}${delimiter} ${names1[i]}`;
    i++;
  }
  i = 0;

  while (j < n2) {
    let secondName = document.getElementById("secondName");
    const delimiter = secondName.innerHTML ? ',' : secondName.innerHTML;
    secondName.innerHTML = `${secondName.innerHTML}${delimiter} ${names2[j]}`;
    j++;
  }
  j = 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 colTop py-3 mb-4">
  <h1 class="text-white">STUDENTS IN CLASS</h1>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td id="firstName"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="secondName"></td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ok soo on the weekend is good but on a week day you show all the names

Comment: I need only 2 names every day

Comment: I did not understand can you please give me an example.

Comment: So for example in monday there will be firstName: name1 and secondName: name2
and on tuesday firstname: name3 and secondName:name4 ... so on. That's what you want or have I made some mistake?

Comment: like I want only name1 and name2 to be shown on screen the first day and then name3 and name4 the second day and so on

Comment: yeah like you said

Comment: So, for that you have two options. First option is you can store rendered index into the local storage and increment the index value in week day and for this you do not require while loop. 
The second option is quite complicated to represent the index of the names array rather than using getDay() use getDate() as getDate() has 28-31 days in total and each getDate() will give unique index but for weekend you may skip certain names so for that you need to implement some logic.
So you my implement any of the two options which fits or if you have better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined due to the equality comparision. The while loop in the else condition is not needed as you only need to print 2 names everyday. So you can do following

1. Save the last index in storage and everytime fetch the next element and display it.
2. Making use of generator function(sample example as shown below)

```js
let dayNr = new Date().getDay();
let names1 = ['name1', 'name3', 'name5', 'name7', 'name9', 'name11', 'name13', 'name15', 'name17', 'name19', 'name21', 'name23', 'name25', 'name27', 'name29', 'name31'];
let names2 = ['name2', 'name4', 'name6', 'name8', 'name10', 'name12', 'name14', 'name16', 'name18', 'name20', 'name22', 'name24', 'name26', 'name28', 'name30'];
let n1 = names1.length;
let n2 = names2.length;


if (dayNr === 0 || dayNr === 6) {
  document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = "WEEKEND";
  document.getElementById("secondName").innerHTML = "WEEKEND";
} else {
  var data1 = data(names1);
  var data2 = data(names2);
  var currVal = document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML
  var currIndex = getIndex(currVal, names1)

  // if the currIndex is equal to length of array then start from first element 
  if(currIndex === n1) {
     currIndex = 0;
  }
  var i = 0, j = 0, val1 = '' , val2 = ''
  while(i <= currIndex) {
      val1 = data1.next().value;
      i++
  }
  while(j <= currIndex) {
      val2 = data2.next().value;
      j++
  }
  document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML = val1;
  document.getElementById("secondName").innerHTML = val2;   
}

function getIndex(val, arr) {
    if(val === "")
       return 0;
    return arr.indexOf(val)
} 
function* data(arr) {
  yield* arr;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 colTop py-3 mb-4">
  <h1 class="text-white">STUDENTS IN CLASS</h1>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td id="firstName"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="secondName"></td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the weekend if  is wrong it should be if (dayNr === 0 || dayNr === 6)

Comment: and the names don't change every day they just stay to name1 and name2

Comment: @MTimo27 You are right that the weekend condition was wrong. Corrected the same now. The names do change. The getIndex function gets the index of the current value. Using that index you can chose the next value from the array and show the same.
Another approach is to save this index in storage(file/db) and fetch it during execution to compute the next index. Please let me know if you have any doubts